# Is it possible to disable the window close button in chrome with Python?

Tags: python

I'm making an HTML editor with python tkinter. Users can type html code and then run it. When they run the code, a chrome window opens, displaying the output of the code (done with `selenium`). When chrome opens, a `stop` button is placed under the `run` button, so users can stop the execution of the code. I want to disable the chrome close button, so users can click the `stop` button instead of closing chrome. I don't want the user to close the window by closing chrome as it slows down the program. In addition, it throws an error if the chrome window is open for too long:

```
Exception ignored in: <function Popen.__del__ at 0x0000022D85EA04C0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Meirom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1055, in __del__
    self._internal_poll(_deadstate=_maxsize)
  File "C:\Users\Meirom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1457, in _internal_poll
    if _WaitForSingleObject(self._handle, 0) == _WAIT_OBJECT_0:
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

Is there a way to disable the close button?

Comment: If this were possible, malware authors would use it to prevent you from closing their windows.

Comment: This would also be very OS-dependent because you're basically asking to disable the window-manager frame